# How to avoid OOM in array explode

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a **26.1 MB** JSON in a single cell and apply the explode_outer function on that column but that column has **6000** array objects. Then finally I got a java heap memory error.

```
var df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("quote","\"").option("escape","\"").load(<INPUT_FILE_PATH>)


df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("select transport,explode_outer(`transport`) from df").show
```

**Executor Memory:: 1G**

If it is a data skewness problem then please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: (1) "cast_as_array"? (2) Why are you still selecting `transport` after the explosion?

Comment: 1. Now edited
2. I want to retain my source

Comment: That does not make much sense after explode. You are duplicating the 26.1MB json, 6000 times

Comment: This is the requirement from one of the users who want to retain his source column that is why I'm asking this case.

Comment: (1) I would really suggest talking to the user (2) Please share the exact error message. This can be OOM error on the driver side which in that case doesn't prevent you from storing the query results.

Comment: OOM error occurs on the executor machines.

Comment: I thought the dataframe size was increased after the array explode function this might be the reason for OOM.

Comment: Off course it is. As I said, "You are duplicating the 26.1MB json, 6000 times"